# Use grep to search for a string in files, include subfolders

Tags: search, shell, find, grep

i have to search for a particular text in files and for that im using grep command but it searches only in current folder.What i want is that using a single grep command i can search a particular thing in the current folder as well as in all of its sub folders.How can i do that???

Comment: Type `grep --help`, and it will tell you exactly what to do.

Comment: tried that as well but its not showing any info regarding to what im seeking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POSIX grep does not support recursive searching - the GNU version of grep does.

```
find . -type f -exec grep 'pattern' {} \;
```

would be runnable on any POSIX compliant UNIX.

Comment: `find . -type f -exec grep 'pattern' {} /dev/null \;` is a top tip I picked up on here for printing the name of the file(s) before the matching line with POSIX grep.

Answer (score 0):

`man grep` says

```
   -R, -r, --recursive
          Read all  files  under  each  directory,  recursively;  this  is
          equivalent to the -d recurse option.
```

Comment: i was trying this only but its not searching in sub directories

Answer (score 0):

And even more common is to use find with xargs, say

```
 find <dir> -type f -name <shellglob> -print0 | xargs grep -0
```

where `-print0` and `-0,` respectively, would use null char to separate entries in order to avoid issues with filenames having space characters.